# EF Core 5.0 with Cosmos - New properties and backing fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using EF Core 5.0 and Cosmos, and I'm trying to work out how to handle the situation where a new property might get added to a model, but older documents don't have this new property.  For example, if the original model looks like:

```
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

... and then some time later a new property is added ...

```
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

... I then run into problems when I try to retrieve a document that only has the original properties (I get a 'non-nullable field must have a value' error).  If I change to data type to `bool?`, it works ... which is understandable.  But I'm trying to avoid using nullable types because of the extra code I would then need to add to check for nulls, etc.

I've tried using 'Backing Fields' to get this to work, like so:

```
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   
   private bool? _isEnabled { get; set; }
   public bool IsEnabled { 
      get => _isEnabled ?? false; 
      set => _isEnabled = value; 
   }
}
```

... and then using the Fluent API in the model builder as follows:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
      .Property(m => m.IsEnabled)
      .HasField("_isEnabled")
      .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

But this generates the following error for me:

*System.InvalidOperationException: The specified field '_isEnabled' could not be found for property 'MyEntity.IsEnabled'*

What am I doing wrong?  Is this never going to work because the property `IsEnabled` doesn't exist in the document?

**Update**: The question is really a question of how to handle a 'schema' change with EF Core and Cosmos.  I know NoSql is 'schema-less' but the reality is that data models change over time and since EF Core migrations don't work with Cosmos, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Does the below answer helps your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the field **_isEnabled** must be **public**.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.propertyaccessmode?view=efcore-6.0) mentions, if you chose **PropertyAccessMode.Field**, an exception will be thrown if it's not possible to read from or write to the field.

Answer (score 0):

What you did above should work fine. I do something similar in certain scenarios and it works fine. (EF 6)

EF6 can even infer the backing field so your binding need only be

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(m => m.IsEnabled)
```

Its only when the backing field can not be inferred do you need to manually define the backing field (my guess is this is something they fixed in EF6)

Answer (score -1):

When `IsEnabled` field is not present in a document, why are you populating it with `false` values?

Consider a situation in which a document has a field with actual `IsEnabled = false` and a document which is artificially having `IsEnabled = false`, **how will you be able to differentiate between them**? Add another field?

**The same questions will be applicable to other properties with different data types.**

This approach looks wrong to me. Rather than this, **if you really don't want to use nullable properties**, you can use [**versioning for your models**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/versioning).

Comment: Ok, `IsEnabled` may have been a bad example, but the point I was trying to make was how can I get EF Core to handle a new property in a model that doesn't exist in old documents, without making the new property nullable?  Perhaps I've introduced a new field that specifies a threshold, or limit, but because that field doesn't exist in old documents, EF Core errors when I try to do a retrieve.  I was hoping 'Backing Fields' would be the answer but it doesn't seem work for me.  I'm at the point where I'm contemplating building my own IRepository and UnitOfWork to handle this.

Comment: Pls use versioning using inheritance. AFAIK, it is the best approach in this scenario